# Can someone explain what is happening with the final part of this RSA example?

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, encryption, rsa, linear-algebra

**The title may not be correct, I was unsure how to phrase my question.**

I am attempting to program with Python3.6 an asymmetric cipher similar to, I believe, that used with RSA  encrypted communication

My *logic* understanding of this is as follows:

```
Person1 (p1) picks two prime numbers say 17 and 19
let p = 17 and q = 19
the product of these two numbers will be called n (n = p * q)
n = 323
p1 will then make public n
P1 will then make public another prime called e, e = 7



Person2(p2) wants to send p1 the letter H (72 in Ascii)
To do this p2 does the following ((72 ^ e) % n) and calls this value M
M = 13
p2 sends M to p1     


p1 receives M and now needs to decrypt it
p1 can do this by calculating D where (e^D) % ((p-1)*(q-1)) = 1
In this example i know D = 247
With D p1 can calculate p2 message using M^D % n
which successfully gives 72 ('H' in ASCII)
```

With this said the following rules must apply:

```
GCD(e,m) = 1
```

where `m = ((p-1)*(q-1))`

otherwise `(e^D) % ((p-1)*(q-1)) = 1` does not exist.

Now comes by issue! :)

**Calculating D where the numbers are not so easy to work with.**

Now please tell me if there is an easier way to calculate D but this is where I got upto using online aid.

(the example I looked at online  used different values so they are as follows:

p=47

q=71

n = p*q = 3337

(p-1)*(q-1) = 3220

e = 79

Now we must find D. We know (e^D) % ((p-1)*(q-1)) = 1

Therefore D = 79^-1 % 3220

The equation is rewritten as 79*d = 1 mod 3220

**This is where I get confused**

Using regular Euclidean Algorithm gcd(79,3220) must equal 1 or there may not actually be a solution (are my descriptions correct here?)

```
3220 = 40*79 + 60 (79 goes into 3220 40 times with remainder 60)
  79 = 1*60 + 19  (The last remainder 60 goes into 79 once with r 19)
  60 = 3*19 + 3   (The last remainder 19 goes into 60 three times with r 3)
  19 = 6*3 + 1    (The last remainder 3 goes into 19 6 times with r 1)
   3 = 3*1 + 0    (The last remainder 1 goes into 3 three times with r 0)
```

The last nonzero remainder is the gcd. Thus gcd(79,3220) = 1 (as it should be)

**The last step here I do not know what on earth is happening**

I am told write the gcd(one) as a linear combination of 19 and 3220 by working back up the tree...

```
1 = 19-6*3
  = 19-6*(60-3*19)
  = 19*19 - 6*60
  = 19*(79-60) - 6*60
  = 19*79 - 25*60
  = 19*79 - 25*(3220-40*79)
  = 1019*79 - 25*3220
```

After this I am left with `1019*79 - 25*3220 = 1` and if i mod 3220 on both sides i get 1019*79 = 1 mod 3220

(the term that contains 3220 goes away because 3220 = 0 mod 3220).

Thus d = 1019.

Comment: I don't have time to answer properly now. Google for "extended Euclidean algorithm" and "modular inverse" and "Bézout's Identity" to learn some fascinating mathematics and the answer to your question.

Comment: [Extended Euclidean Algorithm and Modular Inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures)

Comment: So d=1019. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem is to unwind the following sequence:

```
3220 = 40*79 + 60
  79 = 1*60 + 19
  60 = 3*19 + 3
  19 = 6*3 + 1
   3 = 3*1 + 0
```

First, forget the last row and start from the one with the last non-null remainder.

Then proceed step by step:

```
   1 = 19 - 6*3                                              ; now expand 3
     = 19 - 6*(60 - 3*19)        = 19 - 6*60 + 18*19
     = 19*19 - 6*60                                          ; now expand 19
     = 19*(79 - 1*60) - 6*60     = 19*79 - 19*60 - 6*60
     = 19*79 - 25*60                                         ; now expand 60
     = 19*79 - 25*(3220 - 40*79) = 19*79 - 25*3220 + 1000*79
     = 1019*79 - 25*3220                                     ; done
```

Note that the idea is to expand, at each step, the previous remainder. For instance, when expanding remainder `19` with: `79 - 1*60`, you transform `19*19 - 6*60` into `19*(79 - 1*60) - 6*60`. This lets you regroup around `79` and `60` and keep going.

Comment: The thing that confuses me is the method behind creating the third line of the unwinding series. Am i correct in thinking the second line of the unwinding series is created by expanding the 3 in the first line with (60-3*19), (the third line of the original series)

Comment: Yes. Read also my last edit and let me know if the process is clearer now.

Comment: It has all clicked into place now, thank you very much

Comment: can you just confirm this for me. At the point where I have '1019*79 - 25*3220 = 1' I mod  3220 on both sides which is '1019*79 - 25*3220 % 3220 = 1 % 3220'  this gives me '1019*79 = 1 % 3220' is this right and from here how is it that I should be left with only '1019'

Comment: Yes. If you are trying to solve `D = 79^-1 % 3220`, then `D = 1019`.